# When creating a FormData object from an existing form, are filenames automatically appended and accessible?

Tags: form-data

**Form**

```
<form id="my_form">
<input type="file" name="my_file">
<input type="text" name="field_one">
<input type="text" name="field_two">
<button>send</button>
</form>
```

**Create FormData Object**

```
var myFormData = new FormData($("#my_form")[0]);
```

**Question**

Is the filename of `my_file` accessible even though it hasn't been specifically defined (for DOM manipulation and inserting into database)?

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) states:

> You can also append a File or Blob directly to the FormData object,
>   like this:
>
> `data.append("myfile", myBlob, "filename.txt");`

But it doesn't specify whether a filename is automatically added when creating the `FormData` object from an existing form.

If it is not automatically appended, is the only option to manually create a FormData object through multiple `append()` statements in which case filename definition is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the filename is automatically added (just tested in Chrome and not sure if this differs in other circumstances).

**Steps To Reproduce**

- Go to http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/vsRSf/
- Open Network tab in Developer Tools
- Select two images and click the button
- View the Network tab and you will see the filenames are defined

[image]

The image information is only defined with two parameters, and not the third filename parameter:

```
myFormData.append(name, file);
```

Original fiddle based on this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21901886/1063287