# How to handle multiple file uploads where the name and number of inputs is dynamic?

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, bottle, form-data

I am uploading multiple images through file inputs where the `name` and number of inputs is dynamic.

They do follow this naming convention however:

```
<input name = "image_path" ...
<input name = "image_path_F1" ...
<input name = "image_path_F2" ...
<input name = "image_path_F3" ...
```

The inputs are sent as [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) objects.

When handling a single image from the Python scripts I have previously used:

```
uploaded_image = request.files.name_of_file_input_here
```

**Question**

Is there a generic 'catch all' type of method available with `request.files` which could be used like:

```
uploaded_images = request.files.*all
```

Or will I need to create some sort of loop to handle the possible file names eg:

**Client Side** (jQuery)

```
var names_array = ["image_path","image_path_F1","image_path_F2"];
var length_of_names_array = 3;
```

sent to Python...

**Python**

```
names_array = request.forms.names_array
length_of_names_array = request.forms.length_of_names_array

counter = 1
for i, val in enumerate(range(length_of_names_array)):
    if i == 0:
        constructor = "image_path"
        request.files.constructor
    else:
        constructor = "image_path_F" + str(counter)
        request.files.constructor
        counter += 1
```

The above code will just generate the correct names (and actually I'm not sure if the `request.files` method above would work with `constructor` - **edit**, it doesn't seem to).

There may be a solution to be found in the approach here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3111795/1063287

But I don't quite understand how it operates or exactly how it could be applied to the above scenario:

> If you don't know the key, you can iterate over the files:

```
for filename, file in request.FILES.iteritems():
    name = request.FILES[filename].name
```

Comment: Do you have control over the naming of the form inputs? That would make for an easier solution, I think.

Comment: They are dynamically named following the convention shown above, as there is a dynamic number of inputs.  There's got to be a way to do it, it's just taking me a while to figure out how - ie how to get each input defined in the Python script so that I can put each file in the database.

Comment: Do you, or do you not control the dynamic naming scheme of these inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems a bit dodgy cause I'm not quite sure how it works yet, but it is working.

It's a Mongo implementation, however I am adding it here because I think the takeaway is that you *can* define and access multiple file inputs where the `name` is a dynamic entity as are the number of inputs.

What enabled this was using `iteritems()`.

**Python**

```
for key, value in request.files.iteritems():
    uploaded_image = request.files[key]
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(uploaded_image.filename)
    if ext not in ('.png','.jpg','.jpeg','.JPG','.gif'):
        return "File extension not allowed."
    if uploaded_image and uploaded_image.file:
        raw = uploaded_image.file.read()
        filename = uploaded_image.filename
        dbname = 'grid_files'
        db = connection[dbname]
        fs = gridfs.GridFS(db)
        fs.put(raw,filename=filename, user_email = user_email)
```

This adds each image to the database with a filename and a user email for unique identification (as well as time and length fields automatically generated by MongoDB).

On the client side, the inputs were appended to the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects) object with:

**jQuery**

```
var image_inputs = $("#my_form input[type=file]");
$.each(image_inputs,function(obj,v) { 
var file = v.files[0];
var filename = $(v).attr("data-img_filename");
var name = $(v).attr("id");
myFormData.append(name, file, filename);
});
```

And it seems the filename is automatically included without needing to define it as above:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21942376/1063287